# Did C.S Peirce make any noteworthy contributions to physics or chemistry?

Tags: physics, biographical-details, philosophy-of-science, chemistry

According to [this](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3273015) article

> Peirce was the first to experimentally tie a unit, the meter, to an
> absolute standard, the wavelength of a spectral line

Did C.S Peirce make any other noteworthy contributions to physics or chemistry?

Comment: Wow, that's neat _Physics Today_ ran an article on him!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Peirce received formal training in chemistry at Harvard, and wrote some manuscripts and papers on the subject in 1860s. One of them, [The  Pairing  of  the Elements (Chemical News, 1869)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Writings_of_Charles_S_Peirce_1867_1871/yrHk57CxGNYC?hl=en), published the same year as Mendeleev's celebrated work, even anticipated the periodic law, but in a way common to chemists of the time (Hinrich, Odling, de Chancourtois, Meyer, and Newlands). At the same time, contra Mendeleev, he supported the [Prout’s hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prout%27s_hypothesis) that elements were aggregates of  a  single "protyle" (the hydrogen atom), and attempted to test it experimentally.

Peirce's originality rather manifested in his using of the chemical background as a springboard for analysis of relational logic, diagrammatic reasoning and various classifications he was so fond of. What some characterize as Peirce's philosophical proto-structuralism is directly motivated by his analysis of chemical graphs, see [Bellucci, Peirce’s Chemistry of Concepts](https://www.academia.edu/17198277/Peirces_Chemistry_of_Concepts). It was a major contribution to the philosophy of chemistry, and science generally, that conceptualized the hypothetico-deductive method, the use of abduction and the function of diagrams in science, and chemistry in particular, but not to chemistry itself. The same goes for physics. Aside from methodology, he was one of the first to go against the grain of times (and Kant) to argue from physics for metaphysical indeterminism ("tychism"), but did not do much in physics itself.

Campbell's recent thesis, [The chemistry of relations](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-chemistry-of-relations-%3A-the-periodic-table-the-Campbell/1f558de33b9967262c7ca51af420921995e25a29?p2df), has a chapter dedicated to Peirce's manuscripts and papers on chemistry proper, it is the first study of this kind:

> "*I examine Peirce’s research interest in developing a system for classifying and grouping  the  chemical  elements  according  to  atomic  weight  is  common  to  nineteenth century chemistry. In this respect Peirce’s interest is again main-stream for  the  period.In fact,  as has already  been  discussed  in chapter one, Peirce’s interests were also shared by his tutor Josiah Cooke... The  arrangement  of  the  chemical elements  that  Peirce achieved  is described by Nathan Houser (1982:xx) as going ‘far in Mendeleev’s direction, before Mendeleev’s announcement of the [periodic] law’ and before Mendeleev’s work ‘became known in Western Europe and America’. Here again Peirce’s chemical researches mirror  the  concerns  of  other  researches  in  both  North  America  and  in  Europe.*

> *...Whilst not wishing to challenge Fisch’s view of Peirce as ‘most original and versatile intellect’, I have highlighted that as a chemist, Peirce operated within the boundaries of what Thomas Kuhn (1996) described  as normal  science.  Where  Peirce   differed  was  in  his  ready willingness  to engage with the metaphysical issues that  many chemists,  including his tutor Josiah  Cooke,  chose  to  ignore. During  the  1860s  most  scholars  agree  that  Peirce  almost ‘outsources’ his metaphysics from  Kant  when  forming  his  philosophical  position.  What  I believe is an addition to this scholarship is my claim that Peirce’s Kantian metaphysics emerges in his chemistry.*

> *Of  significance  is  that  in1869  Peirce,  by  employing  inductive  reasoning,  argues  for  an orderly arrangement of the chemical elements. That same year Peirce publishes a series of three  papers  which  includes  a  justification  for  inductive  reasoning  which denies J.S Mill’s defence in terms of the orderliness of nature. I would argue that Peirce does not deny the discoverability  of  regularities  in  the  world;  rather  the  insufficiency  of  such  an  appeal  to order to justify inductive reasoning. As we have seen Peirce’s justification turns on the likelihood that in the longer term inquirers –such as chemists seeking a ordered system for the  chemical  elements –would be ‘fated’ on occasion to be successful  in their inductions, inductive reasoning  being, at least at this stage in Peirce’s philosophy,the  only  form  of ‘synthetic reasoning’ inquirers possess.*

Answer (score 3):

The [*Physics Today* article](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3273015) shows that Michelson knew of C. S. Peirce's unpublished results on measuring the wavelength of sodium emission:

> Michelson realized that the interferometer he and Morley had developed and were just then using to detect ether drift could also be used to make precise wavelength measurements. In June 1887, after getting initial results in their epochal experiment on the speed of light, Michelson and Morley conducted preliminary spectroscopic metrology measurements. Their paper “On a Method of making the Wave-length of Sodium Light the actual and practical Standard of Length” begins, “The first actual attempt to make the wave-length of sodium light a standard of length was made by Peirce.”<sup>15</sup> But, they pointed out, Peirce’s measurements, “which have not as yet been published” (and never would be), had many systematic errors.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>15. A. Michelson, and E. Morley, Am. J. Sci. **34**, 427 (1887).</sub>

Peirce's surveying work required determining the length of pendula accurately, which is related to his contributions in geodesy ([*Complete Dictionary of Scientific Biography* article on Peirce](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/philosophy-and-religion/philosophy-biographies/charles-sanders-peirce#articleWrapper-961088)):

> In 1879 Peirce succeeded in determining the length of the meter from a wavelength of light. Benjamin Peirce described this feat, an adumbration of the work of Michelson, as “the only sure determination of the meter, by which it could be recovered if it were to be lost to science.” By 1882 Peirce was engaged in a mathematical study of the relation between the variation of gravity and the figure of the earth. He claimed that “divergencies from a spherical form can at once be detected in the earth’s figure by this means,” and that “this result puts a new face on the relation of pendulum work to geodesy.”

Answer (score 2):

Pierce was educated as a chemist and employed as a scientist. He considered himself primarily as a logician in the American school of analytic philosophy.

His biographer Joseph Brent, called him 'he was at first, almost stupefied, and then aloof, cold, depressed, extremely suspicious, impatient of the slightest crossing and subject to violent outbursts of temper.' And according to Wikipedia, it's consequences might have led to his later social isolation.

Given that his main employment, intermittently, was by the US Coast Survey and its successor, the US Coast and Geodetic Survey, it's not surprising that he was responsible for some innovations in metrology.

*Physics Today*, confirms that Pierce 'was the first to experimentally tie a unit, the meter, to an absolute standard, a spectral line' but they go on to add

> For several reasons that contribution has not received much attention. First, he never finished it to his satisfaction and only left fragmentary reports in his 12 000 published pages, and 80,000 hand-written pages of notes and letters - mostly on logic, mathematics, science and philosophy.

They go onto say that:

> Pierce's chaotic personal and professional life has hindered a comprehensive assessment of contributions.

So I expect, we will find out - eventually ...